# How to discover Unique Device IDs in Bluetooth network with Web APIs?

Tags: html, bluetooth, network-protocols

How to discover Unique Device IDs in Bluetooth network with Web APIs, **not with native Java APIs**? Any working example?

WebKit still has not implemented this APIs:

- Discovery API https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=101162
- Bluetooth API https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=101034

and Mozilla are implementing for B2G https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAPI, issues https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=727618, https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=674737

Answer (score 1):

Whilst not a final API Chrome has Bluetooth support in Linux and ChromeOS http://developer.chrome.com/apps/bluetooth.html#method-getDevices

Comment: Thanks! It is currently implemented just on ChromeOS. 
Chrome Bluetooth API implementation: 
Windows http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=135470, 
Mac http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=135472, 
Linux http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=135467